# Zooming in Eclipse GEF to specific location

Tags: eclipse, zooming, java, eclipse-gef

Hello I am new in Eclipse GEF and I am having problem with zooming.

Basically I would like to have this functionality: 
Whenever I close my Editor View I would like to have Editor zoomed with previous scale and most importantly to the same location.

I was trying to achieve such functionality via Viewport, but I got stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I have found solution via `setViewLocation(Position p)` method.
The tricky part lies elsewhere - before executing such method viewport must be in valid state,

so best approach is to execute `performUpdate()` on viewport's UpdateManager. Another tricky situation might occur if you are setting such position in GEF Editor because there setting location must be executed in `initializeGraphicalViewer()` method **NOT** in `configureGraphicalViewer()` method.

So in the end code should look like this:

```
@Override
protected void initializeGraphicalViewer() {

    super.initializeGraphicalViewer();
    final GraphicalViewer viewer = getGraphicalViewer();
    viewer.setContents(getModel());
    ScalableFreeformRootEditPart rootEditPart = (ScalableFreeformRootEditPart) viewer.getRootEditPart();

    Viewport viewport = (Viewport) rootEditPart.getFigure();
    viewport.getUpdateManager().performUpdate();
    viewport.setViewLocation(getModel().getZoomPosition());
}
```